# In Perl, best way to insert a char every N chars

Tags: algorithm, perl, string-matching

I would like to find the best way in Perl to insert a char every N chars in a string.
Suppose I have the following :

```
my $str = 'ABCDEFGH';
```

I would like to insert a space every two chars, so that I get:

```
my $finalstr = 'AB CD EF GH';
```

The innocent way would be:

```
my $finalstr;
while ($str =~ s/(..)//) {
    $finalstr .= $1.' ';
}
```

(But the last space does not make me happy.)

Can we do better? Is it possible using a single substitution pattern s///, especially to use that same string $str (and not using $finalstr)?

---

The next step: do the same but with text before and after patterns to be cut (and to be kept, for sure), say for example '<<' and '>>':

```
my $str       = 'blah <<ABCDEFGH>> blah';
my $finalstr1 = 'blah <<AB CD EF GH>> blah';
my $finalstr2 = 'blah << AB CD EF GH >> blah';  # alternate
```

Comment: Hi, this kind of question belongs on SO. (I flagged it for moderator attention, so they will migrate it there soon, please do not double post it there, just wait a bit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) to insert a space:

```
my $str = 'ABCDEFGH';

$str =~ s/..\K(?=.)/ /sg;

use Data::Dump;
dd $str;
```

Outputs:

```
"AB CD EF GH"
```

#### Enhancement for limiting the Translation

If you want to apply this modification to only part of the string, break it into steps:

```
my $str = 'blah <<ABCDEFGH>> blah';

$str =~ s{<<\K(.*?)(?=>>)}{$1 =~ s/..\K(?=.)/ /sgr}esg;

use Data::Dump;
dd $str;
```

Outputs:

```
"blah <<AB CD EF GH>> blah"
```

Comment: Does the job #1, carefully not inserting a space at the end of the string, thanks. Would it also be applicable when the part of string to be processed is inside '<<' and '>>'? How to start and stop this replacement based on these patterns?

Comment: The easiest solution is to break up the job into two steps.

Comment: Nested string translations... waw I just learned special features of Perl :) Thanks for this smart answer.

Comment: @RichardHuxton `\K` is best documented in [perlre - Extended Patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).  Just search for `\K` as it's in the subsection on Look-Around Assertions

Comment: @Teuxe Note the `/r` [Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) requires perl v5.14 or later.  It's possible to get the same effect though using `s{(...)}{ (my $text = $1) =~ s/.../.../; $text}` for earlier perl versions

Comment: How would I insert a character every N, where N can be anything?

Answer (score 4):

The best solution using substitutions would probably be `s/\G..\K/ /sg`. Why?

- The `\G` anchores at the current “position” of the string. This position is where the last match ended (usually this is set to the beginning of the string. If in doubt, set `pos($str) = 0`). Because we use the `/g` modifier, this will be where the previous substitution ended.
- The `..` matches any two characters. Note that we also use the `/s` modifier which causes `.` to really match any character, and not just the `[^\n]` character class.
- The `\K` treats the previous part of the regex as a look-behind, by not including the previously matched part of the string in the substring that will be substituted. So  `\G..\K` matches the zero length string after two arbitrary characters.
- We substitute that zero length string with a single space.

I'd let the regex engine handle the substitution, rather than manually appending `$1 . " "`. Also, my lookbehind solution avoids the cost of using captures like `$1`.

Comment: Almost fine for point #1 except for the last space added while not wanted; cf Miller's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `//g` modifier with its many capabilities. See e.g. [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) for an introduction to the intricacies of global matching.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like...

```
$str =~ s/(..)/$1 /sg;
```

***update***: For more complex substitutions as the one you are asking in the second part of your question, you can use the `e` modifier that allows you to evaluate arbitrary perl code:

```
sub insert_spcs {
    my $str = shift;
    join ' ', $str =~ /(..?)/sg
}

my $str = 'blah <<ABCDEFGH>> blah';
$str =~ s/<<(.*?)>>/'<< '.insert_spcs($1).' >>'/se;
```

Comment: I believed the 'g' option was parsing the string from its beginning each time, so it would have be an infinite recursion. But actually it does the job for this first point, thanks.

Comment: my $str = 'blah <<ABCDEFGH>> blah';
    $For the second point:

    my $str = 'blah <<ABCDEFGH>> blah';
    $str =~ s/<<(.*)(..)(.*)>>/<<\1 \2 \3>>/sg;
    print $str."\n";

produces the output:

    blah <<ABCDEF GH >> blah

which does not match my requirement.

Comment: Calling functions from the right-side of the substitution operator is very interesting, it keeps the meaning of operation clearly understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd split the text with `m//g` and use `join`:

```
my $input = "ABCDEFGH";
my $result = join " ", ( $input =~ m/(..)/g );
say "RESULT <$result>";'
```

Yields

```
RESULT <AB CD EF GH>
```

Comment: That fails when the `$input` has an odd number of chars. It can be fixed as `$input =~ m/(..?)/g`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better, but just for giggles:

```
join ' ', grep length, split /(..)/, 'ABCDEFGH';
```